# How to bypass startup form in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Hi I want to get to the VB modules in Access 2007. Normally I would do it by Alt+F11, but it doesn't work.

Thanks,

nikolz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting it while holding down the shift key.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Access 2007, it's my understanding that if the programmer disables the Startup bypass hotkeys - there is no way to bypass it.  However, it's not an option in the menu - you have to write in the disable feature programmatically.  Otherwise, the Shift key is the most common hotkey to bypass Startup scripts.

Comment: Actually, bypassing the key programmatically via "AllowBypassKey" already worked in Access 97.

Comment: See?  I learn something new everyday - that I did not know.  :)